# How to smoothly animate a Bootstrap well on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

Okay so I have to make a `well` expand by showing buttons when you hover over it.

I've managed to do but the expansion is very sudden (Y'know, like appearing and disappearing out of nowhere).

I'd like to ask how I can animate it to make the hover more appealing to look at.

**This is what I have right now:**

```
var origWell= $('#NoteWell').html();
$("#NoteWell").hover(function(){
        $(this).html(originalContent + '<div type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" title="Stop" data-content="Stop Note Conversion" onclick=stopNote()>Stop</div>');
        }, function(){
        $(this).html(origWell);
    });
```

Relevant HTML (as requested) is basically:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="Currencies" class="row" align=center>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#Notes"><div id="CurrencyWell" class="well well-sm col-sm-2"><h4>Notes<br><span id="note">0</span></h4></div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mind providing your HTML?

Comment: don't change the content, use CSS to size and css transitions to animate the size changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the jQuery slide or fade effects (`slideIn()`, `slideOut()` / `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()`)

```js
$("#NoteWell").hover(function() {
  $(this).find('button').slideDown();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('button').slideUp();
});


$("#NoteWell2").hover(function() {
  $(this).find('button').fadeIn();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('button').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
html {margin:2em;}

#NoteWell button, #NoteWell2 button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="NoteWell" class="well">
  Button slides up/down
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" title="Stop" data-content="Stop Note Conversion" onclick="stopNote()">Stop</button>
</div>

<div id="NoteWell2" class="well">
  Button fades in/out
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" title="Stop" data-content="Stop Note Conversion" onclick="stopNote()">Stop</button>
</div>
```